# How to trigger auto update Google BigQuery Dataset every time CSV upload on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to automate the entire data loading, that means whenever I upload a file to Google Cloud storage, it automatically triggers the data to be uploaded into the BigQuery dataset. I know that there is a daily set timing update available, but I want something where it only triggers whenever the CSV file is re-uploaded.

Comment: Do you want to load the data of your file into BigQuery table? Or do you want to read it from GCS for updating other tables?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I would want that when the user uploads a csv file, it triggers a BigQuery SQL code (which is already saved). My aim is to create a data flow (a bunch of connected, interdependent SQL queries) which runs every time the CSV file is uploaded (as the data processing would happen on it)

Comment: Do you need to link all the queries ? When one is finish, you run the another one? Is the data need to be copied or a view is enough?

Comment: As of now, I had multiple queries. I was planning to have all of them in one saved query. But the issue is, I am using multiple uploaded datasets to get the final table. This eventually flows into Google Data Studio. I would want if any of the input datasets is uploaded, the query runs. (I can merge all the sub steps into one single query though)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere could you help me with the automation part and the best practices?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 possibilities:

- Either you react on event. I mean you can [plug a function on Google Cloud Storage events](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize). In the event message you have the file stored in GCS and you can do what you want with it, for exemple [run a load job from Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage).
- Or, do nothing! Let the file in GCS and [create a BigQuery federated table to read into GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage)

With this 2 solutions, your data are accessible by BigQuery. Your Datastudio graph can query BigQuery, the data are here. However.

- The load job is more efficient, you can partition and clusterize your data for optimize the speed and the cost. However, you duplicate your data (from GCS) and you have to code and to run your function. Anyway, cost is very low and function very simple. For Big Data it's my recommended solution
- The federated table are very useful when the quantity of data is low and for occasional access or for prototyping. You can't clusterize and partition your data and the speed is lower than data loaded into BigQuery (because the CSV parsing is performing on the fly).

So, Big Data is a wide area: do  you need to transform the data before the load? can you transform them after the log? How can you link query the ones after the others? ....

Don't hesitate if you have other questions on this!